# What is the Gremlin query that can get me all the vertices either directly or indirectly connected to one specific vertex

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I need help with a Gremlin query that can output all the vertices related to one specific vertex A and their cascading related vertices (which means all the vertices related directly or indirectly to A).

For example, in a graph

```
A -> B -> C
D
```

Running this query on A will give me B and C.

The solution I have right now is an ugly one:

`g.V('A').both(); g.V('A').both().both();`

etc

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted. Upvoted since it's a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution isn't ugly; it only lacks a bit of iteration and an exit condition.

Do you require a maximum depth? Depending on the shape of your graph, the query you want to execute could be returning all vertices of that graph.

Assuming a toy modern TinkerGraph created in the Gremlin console:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
```

This query could be helpful:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(both().simplePath()).emit().times(3).dedup()
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[5]
```

*"Starting from vertex with id=1, traverse the graph in all directions up to a maximum depth of 3 while discarding previously visited paths. The `emit()` step ensures that all traversed vertices found along the way, and not just leaves, are returned."*

Chances are high that you want to figure out which vertices are linked to that vertex only via specific edges. In such case, you could be passing label(s) to the `both()` step, and/or maybe chain a few filters.

When developing your query, feel free to chain the `path()` step to better understand the output.

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(both().simplePath()).emit().times(3).dedup().path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[1],v[4]]
==>[v[1],v[3],v[6]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
```

There are other ways to solve this, but this query should get you started and familiarize yourself with basic Gremlin steps and concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like the repeat() step is not supported by the Gremlin Graph Explorer I was using (it took forever to load the graph every time) but your query fix the problem on web.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted since it was useful to you.

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to avoid repeat() step and still solve the problem elegantly? Or is there any ways such that we don't have to type in A every time we use both()?

Comment: I don't think you can really avoid `repeat()` here - there's nothing inelegant to do so in Gremlin terms (do/while or while/do semantics are supported this way). For question #2, and if I understand you well, you could be passing a variable to `g.V(some_value).repeat(...).` or maybe use `g.V().has("name", some_unique_name)` as a starting point

Comment: Hi, sorry for such a later reply. I am using a Gremlin Graph Explorer to read and visualize the map from Azure Cosmos Db and I just figured that it does not support repeat() step and subgraph() step and next() step. To rephrase my second question, is there a way to have a variable a = g.V('id') such that the user does not need to type in the id again and again for my sample .both.both input?

Comment: any way to repeat till all vertices explored ... sort of line transitive closure from a vertex ? i cant fogure out what to pass in "until"